# Fetch Row contents of a table

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-1.1

I am working on **ASP.Net 1.1**.

In a page I have table as :

```
<table id="dlInterior" Width="300" Runat="server" CellSpacing="0" CellPadding="0">
    <tr>
        <td id="inttd" vAlign="top" width="350" runat="server"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**On Page load** - I am adding rows to this table dynamically as :

```
public static void DisplayDecodedInfo(object[] decodedValues, HtmlTable tableToAdd)
{
    try
    {
        if(decodedValues.Length > 0)
        {
            foreach(string item in decodedValues)
            {
                HtmlTableCell tdInterior = new HtmlTableCell();
                HtmlTableCell tdInterior1 = new HtmlTableCell();
                tdInterior1.Attributes.Add("Width","3%");
                tdInterior1.Attributes.Add("Align","Center");
                HtmlTableRow trInterior = new HtmlTableRow();
                trInterior.Attributes.Add("Height","20px");
                tdInterior.Attributes.Add("padding-left","2cm");
                tdInterior.InnerHtml = "<b>*</b> " + item;
                trInterior.Controls.Add(tdInterior1);
                trInterior.Controls.Add(tdInterior);
                tableToAdd.Controls.Add(trInterior);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now On **SAVE button click event** of the page, *I need to fetch these string values row by row .*

Please suggest how is it possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you cannot just fetch the content of a HTML table from a server side script. So what should you do is also render hidden fields for data and on submit you can find it in `Request.Form[]`.

Answer (score 0):

I would cache these `decodedValues` in `Session` or `ViewState` and retrieve the array from there on postback if needed.